# Directly identifying grammar as SLR(1), LR(0), LR(1) etc

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine whether a grammar is LL(1) LR(0) SLR(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475949/how-to-determine-whether-a-grammar-is-ll1-lr0-slr1)

Is there any direct way i.e. without constructing parsing table, to find out whether a grammar is SLR(1), LR(0), LR(1) or LALR(1).
For example, Here is the grammar

```
S->Sd|cAe
A->Sa|S|a
```

Now How can we found which class this grammar belongs to ? Is it SLR(1), LR(0), LR(1) or LALR(1) ?

Comment: @outis: yes I checked that question but the answers there only tell how to find for LL(1). But I want for others also as I have mentioned in my question.

Comment: Aaron mentions how to do it for other grammars, though he doesn't give examples: "look for violations of the constraints of various grammar types". Perhaps not entirely helpful, but it's a start.