# Recognising LL and LR grammars... NOT parser

Tags: grammar, lr-grammar, ll-grammar

If I am given a CFG by looking at it can I decide whether it is a LL class of grammar or LR class of grammar? When I searched for this question on Google what I got was how the parsers for these grammars work, but, that is not what I want. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: read this also: [How to determine whether a language is LL(1) LR(0) SLR(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475949/how-to-determine-whether-a-language-is-ll1-lr0-slr1) and [How to identify whether a grammar is LL(1), LR(0) or SLR(1)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496642/how-to-identify-whether-a-grammar-is-ll1-lr0-or-slr1)

Answer (score 1):

You can recognize if a grammar is not LL if it has left recursion.
Example:

```
S -> A | y
A -> Az
```

Comment: I was just about to give this answer :)

Comment: It's funny how quick it was upvoted. :D

Comment: The absense of left recursion is **not** condition enough for a grammar to be LL. Lookup the definition of LL in Wikipedia. This grammar is not LL: ``S -> aSa | ε``

Comment: @Apalala Read **well** what I wrote. I didn't say *any grammar without left recursion is LL*, but I said *if it's left recursive, it is not LL*.

Comment: @Samy You're right. Please make any minor edit to your answer so I can remove the downvote.

Comment: @Samy You didn't, edit your answer so I can remove the downvote. Yet remember that removing left recursion is a mechanical process, and that makes left-recursion not a primary criteria for LL-ness.

Comment: @Apalala Answer edited. — What would be another criteria for LL-ness?